# Azure Function list operation show index out of range

Tags: python, azure, function

I'm writing some script on Azure function with python, which want to handle the csv file which was upload to blob storage.
The coding I tested pass in local, but it got error on Azure function.

Result: Failure Exception: IndexError: list index out of range Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 355, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 542, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/csvhandler/**init**.py", line 28, in main text1=list1[0]

**Not quite sure why it said *list index out of range Stack*, the list index should begin from 0..**

input string

ab,cd,ef\r\n12,34,56\r\nff,gg,ee\r\n

code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list1=[]

def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> None:
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger function processed %s', inputblob.name)
    str1 = inputblob.read().decode('utf-8-sig') 
    str1 = str1.split('\\r\\n')   #split the string in list str1 = "ab,cd,ef\r\n12,34,56\r\nff,gg,ee\r\n"
    str1 = str1[0:-1]
    for i in range(0,len(str1)):    #split the list which can be written into pandas DataFrame
        str2=str1[i].split(',')
        list1.append(str2)
    print(str1)
    
    text1=list1[0]   #verify if the element correct
    text2=list1[1]
    text3=list1[2]
    text4=list1[3]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(list1[1:], columns=list1[0])  #create the dataframe
    
    outstr=df.to_csv(index=False)   #transfer the output to string
    outputblob.set(outstr)          #output the string in the blob
```

**In the other hand, would anyone suggest if we can explore the edited dataframe as csv to blob storage? I can't find much info here.**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you defined your variable `list1` outside the scope of your main function, meaning it is a global variable. With Azure Functions, I believe you have to explicitly declare global variables inside your main function in order to edit them. Because of this, your list may not be updating when you append the elements from your csv file, which would cause the list index error. There should be two ways to fix this (and possibly others as well):

1. Define `list1` as a local variable inside the main function.

```
    def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> None:
        logging.info('Python Queue trigger function processed %s', inputblob.name)

        list1 = []
        
        str1 = inputblob.read().decode('utf-8-sig')
```

2. Declare `list1` as a global variable, so that it can be used inside of your main function. (See Azure Functions docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#global-variables)).

```
    list1 = []

    def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> None:
        logging.info('Python Queue trigger function processed %s', inputblob.name)
        
        global list1
        
        str1 = inputblob.read().decode('utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your input. I have modified my code, but still got error.